# How to create a single form for donations?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a commerce module setup which allows for donations on a site I'm working on. Everything runs smoothly - you make a donation, it gets added to your cart, and when you're done you go to your cart, you click the checkout button, you enter cc info and bob's yer uncle (USAePay is the cc vendor).

However, the client is asking that one single page not do it this way at all - they want the information to all happen on one single page. You enter all your info - billing info, name/email info, cc info, donation amount, all on the same page. And clicking "**Donate now**" does everything that you previously did in a few steps. And by everything, I do mean **everything** - not a different chunking of panels, I mean it all happens on one page.

It really seems like clicking a link is creating a new cart of its own and taking you directly to checkout, and the styling of the checkout page is maybe different from other ones. Not sure how I'd accomplish that, though.

Questions:

- is this even possible? I don't want to lead them on and let them think it's possible when it's not.
- if it IS possible, how? And please don't just say "a module."

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Commerce Buy One Click module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_buy_one_click).

> Commerce Buy One Click Module allows customers to checkout directly
>   from the product page with just one click, skipping the annoying
>   checkout steps.

Comment: D'argh! Spoke too soon. It would appear that this doesn't do what I need it to do. This would only send the administrator an email saying 1-click was requested, rather than bringing a user (anonymous or not) to a dedicated checkout page.

Comment: well that seems mostly useless...

Answer (score 0):

If "*I have a `commerce` module setup*" means that you're using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) (because its project namespace is `commerce` also), then have a look at the [Commerce Donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) module. From its project page:

> This module provides a donation line item type along with a donation product and product display. This is partially based on Randy Fay's excellent screencast at http://commerceguys.com/blog/using-custom-line-items-provide-donation-fe...
>
> It uses the [Select or Other](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module to provide the donation amount form field. If you need to modify the default donation option values, then install the [Commerce Customizable Products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) module in order to modify the line item type form settings.
>
> In addition to being able to create a donation product, this module also provides a donation checkout pane, allowing customers to add a donation to their order as part of the checkout process.

Here is a screenprint (from its project page also) of how that ***checkout pane***:

[image]

So selecting an option for "***Donate to us!***" that differs from `None`, is the only action needed to allow for donations, and similar to what is written in your question:

- it does everything that you previously did in a few steps.
- not a different chunking of panels.
- it all happens on one page.

**Note**: refer to the tutorial/screencast "[Using Custom Line Items To Provide a Donation Feature to Drupal Commerce](http://commerceguys.com/blog/using-custom-line-items-provide-donation-feature-drupal-commerce)" for a great introduction to this module.